# Proving a property of the Fourier coefficients of a continuous function

Tags: calculus, analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

We have that the function f defined on [-$\pi$,$\pi$] is continuous, and we want to prove the following statement about its Fourier coefficients $c_n$

$$c_n = c_{-n}\;\; \text{for all}\; n\; \Rightarrow \text{f even}. $$

I am using the convention

$$c_n = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(t)e^{-int}dt .$$

I have come up with two ways to show it but I am not sure if there are any flaws with method 2.

Method 1:
$$c_n = c_{-n} \iff \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(t)e^{-int}dt = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(t)e^{int}dt $$

The variable change $t\to -t$ in the second integral gives the equality
$$ \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(t)e^{-int}dt = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(-t)e^{-int}dt \\
\iff \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} (f(t)-f(-t))e^{-int}dx = 0 $$
Now, the integrand in the last integral is a continuous function and for such functions the integral is zero iff the integral is identically zero over that interval. Hence

$$ (f(t)-f(-t))e^{-int} = 0 \iff f(t) = f(-t), t\in[-\pi,\pi] \iff \text{f even}. $$

Method 2:

$$ c_n = c_{-n} \iff \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(t)e^{-int}dt = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(t)e^{int}dt \\
\iff \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(t)(e^{int}-e^{-int})dx = 0 \iff \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(t)sin(nt) dt = 0 \\
\Rightarrow f(t)sin(nt)\;\; \text{odd}\; \Rightarrow f(t)\; \text{even}.$$

I am unsure of whether I can conclude that f(t)sin(nt) is an odd function. I guess there is the possibility that the integral over the symmetric interval vanishes for other reasons. I think the implication only goes in the direction of "if g is odd then $\int_{-a}^a g(t)dt = 0$".

I also wanted to ask if the statements
$$ c_n = -c_{-n} \; \Rightarrow \; \text{f odd}. $$
and
$$\overline{c_n} = c_{-n} \; \Rightarrow \; \text{f real-valued}$$
are proven in the same manner as the above.

Comment: It's not true that if the integral is zero then the integrand has to be zero or odd. However, there is a result that says that if the Fourier coefficients of an $L^1$ function (in particular, continuous functions) vanish, then the function is zero. Now, look at the Fourier coefficients of $f(t)-f(-t)$ etc.

Comment: @redwhisker Yeah it's true that the function need not be zero for the integral to vanish. I was thinking of some other result, but I can't find what it was. It was for non-negative continuous functions I believe.